# Cannot run WebApp in .Net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, servicestack

So I created a new web app using $x new web WebApp in my cmd and when I open the .sln file in VS and go to press run I get this page:

[image]

But what I want is this:

[image]

Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: I have added the [ServiceStack] tag since these steps and screenshot are from the [ServiceStack documentation](https://docs.servicestack.net/create-your-first-webservice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than taking an eternity on first run for VS to download all the debug symbols, once loaded it's working as expected:

```
$ x new web WebApp
```

Double click WebApp.sln, opens into **Visual Studio Community 2019** then after clicking **Continue** to run it eventually launches the default website at `https://localhost:5001`

[image]

Other things you can try:

- Use `CTRL+F5` to **Run** the App instead of debugging it, in case there was an issue with downloading the debug symbols.

Under the run button click **WebApp** to run the app with **dotnet run** instead of **IIS Express**:

[image]

If you have VS Code you can you can run the .NET App with `dotnet run` in the **WebApp** host folder:

```
$ cd WebApp
$ dotnet run
```

Use [JetBrains Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) (I can't recommend it enough), I used to have frequent VS crashes, lock ups and white screens of death with VS.NET, switching to Rider has made me vastly more productive thanks to its smarter IDE, navigation and refactoring tools as well as no longer experiencing any of the slowness & buggy issues I used to have with VS.